# Is it possible to change title formatting in ConTeXt's \completecontent?

Tags: table-of-contents, context

Say there's a document that goes like the following:

```
\starttext
\completecontent
\dorecurse{10}{\expanded{\section{Section \recurselevel}}}
\stoptext
```

How do can one change the formatting of the title `\completecontent` does? Wiki says ToC is a ConTeXt list, but I couldn't found any option on `\setupcombinedlist[content]` to do so, nor something like `\setuphead[content]`.

Well, of course, one can do

```
\definehead[MyToc][section]
\setuphead[MyToC][...]
\starttext
\startMyToc
\placecontent
\stopMyToc
\dorecurse{10}{\expanded{\section{Section \recurselevel}}}
\stoptext
```

But I want to know if there's a more straightforward way to accomplish this.

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to configure the look of the title of the table of contents.

If I read the source correctly, it inserts a `title` head. Therefore,

```
\setuphead[title][color=red]
\starttext
\completecontent
\dorecurse{10}{\expanded{\section{Section \recurselevel}}}
\stoptext
```

Should work. Indeed, the output is

[image: output with red title]

Answer (score 3):

`\completecontent` is merely a shorthand for `\placecombinedlist[content]` wrapped in a `title` element.  That means you can easily customize every aspect of the table of contents by using the combined list directly.

Another hint: Always use the `\start...\stop` variant of macros.

```
\definehead
  [tochead]
  [title]
  [color=red]

\starttext

\starttochead[title={Table of Contents}]
  \placecombinedlist[content]
\stoptochead

\dorecurse{10}{
  \startsection[title={Section \recurselevel}]
  \stopsection
}

\stoptext
```